# Get the response of one controller in another controller in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to Call the function from one controller into another

> 1. Controller1.js 2) Controller2.js

Controller1.js file code

var Controller2= require('../controllers/Controller2.js');

```
exports.getlist = function (req, res, next) {
    Controller2.commonCode(req,res,function (err, response) { 
                  console.log(response);
   });
};
```

Controller2.js file code

```
module.exports.commonCode= function (req,res,callback) {
    var data = { 'data': 'Save successfully' };
    console.log(data);
    callback(null,data);

};
```

> I am getting output for console.log(data)  but console.log(response)
> is showing undefined. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

it's better to not call a function of a controller from another controller, instead if you think a function will be used by multiple controllers then put it inside a `utils` folder for example, and call it from everywhere.

1- create a utils folder and put `commonCode` inside it:

```js
module.exports= function (req,res,callback) {
    var data = { 'data': 'Save successfully' };
    console.log(data);
    callback(null,data);
};
```

2- import it inside controller1:

```js
const commonCode = require('./utils/commonCode')

exports.getlist = function (req, res, next) {

    commonCode(req,res,function (err, response) { 
                  console.log(response);
   });
};
```

3- then you just need to call `getList()` function